# Using .HasValue() in LinQ when dealing with a Nullable type, is there a way to get rid of "Possible SystemInvalidException"?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, nullable

I have a list of `Foo's`.

`Foo` has a `CreateDate` of type `DateTime?`

I want to get the oldest `Foo`. I tryed with the intuitive way, but I get a possible `System.InvalidOperationException`.

```
DateTime oldestFoo = 
(from f in allFoos where f.CreateDate.HasValue select f.CreateDate.Value).Min();
```

Is there something I missed or is it just not possible this way?

I can do it without LinQ this way, but I want to learn the other approach too.

```
DateTime oldestFoo = DateTime.MaxValue;
foreach (var foo in allFoos)
{
    if (foo.CreateDate.HasValue && oldestFoo > foo.CreateDate)
    {
        oldestFoo = (DateTime)foo.CreateDate;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want the result to be when there aren't any results with values? (A short but complete program would help here...)

Comment: If there aren't any, oldestFoo can be DateTime.MaxValue.

Comment: My point is: how would you expect `Min()` to know that?

Comment: First I wrote the foreach example, that works perfectly, but I wanted a LinQ version, and I just don't get why I can't use `HasValue()`and `.Value` like. Hmm. So the real problem is, that I don't have the `DateTime.MaxValue`included in my LinQ code.

Comment: Yes I get it now I think. All my focus was on `HasValue()` and `Value`:)

Comment: Thanks for removing my tunnel-vision and getting me back on the right track.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just in case you're still stuck, you might want to consider using `DefaultIfEmpty` - see if this helps:

```
DateTime oldestFoo = allFoos.Where(f => f.CreateDate.HasValue)
                            .Select(f => f.CreateDate.Value)
                            .DefaultIfEmpty(DateTime.MaxValue)
                            .Min();
```

I *don't* think you want to use `GetValueOrDefault` within your query, as otherwise you'll *still* have a problem if the first query returns no results at all.

Comment: Hah! Awesome. Forest from the trees.

Comment: It says, that oldestFoo is of type DateTime? I can cast the query to (DateTime) but then I still have the SystemInvalidException. Is it just me?

Comment: @radbyx: Apologies - I've got a bug in the `Select`. Will fix.

Comment: Np. `f.CreateDate.Value` still give a "Possible System.InvalidOperationException". I guess Resharper understand "If(...HasValue) ...Value" but not "Where(...HasValue).Select(...Value), even though it's look the same for me.

Comment: @radbyx: Are you *only* worried about what ReSharper says? It's just wrong here (assuming the property value doesn't change between the Where and the Select). Don't expect it to know everything - use your judgement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `GetValueOrDefault` method, which doesn't cause an exception, and as there are no null values at that point, the result is the same:

```
DateTime oldestFoo = (
  from f in allFoos
  where f.CreateDate.HasValue
  select f.CreateDate.GetValueOrDefault()
).Min();
```

Comment: Could you also be assured that a cast would not fail in this case? `select (DateTime)f.CreateDate`, because you already ensured that it had a value, with `HasValue`?

Comment: @dwerner: Even if you know that there are no null values at that point, the compiler doesn't know that. It doesn't do enough analysis on the code to realise that the `HasValue` condition weeds out the null values in another part of the code.

Comment: Edit this with GetValueOrDefault(DateTime.MaxValue) and I think it's right yes?

Comment: And maybe remove where too then? Like this DateTime oldestFoo = (
  from f in allFoos
  select f.CreateDate.GetValueOrDefault(DateTime.MaxValue)
).Min();

Comment: @Guffa - I just asked for educational purposes. DateTime?.GetValueOrDefault works, but casting does as well. The compiler then sees it as a value type. I'll give you +1 for the more readable answer.

Comment: @radbyx: Well, in this case that would work too, because `DateTime.MaxValue` is larger than any other `DateTime` value. It won't work in situations where you can't convert a null value into a dummy value that won't be used.

Comment: @dwerner: Casting works the same way as using `.Value`, you may get a compiler warning because the cast in itself could potentially cause an exception.

Comment: Ah, I tried using csharp-repl in mono. That might explain it.

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime oldestFoo =
    (from f in allFoos select f.CreateDate).Min() ?? DateTime.MaxValue;
```

Or, slightly more succinctly:

```
DateTime oldestFoo =
    allFoos.Select(f => f.CreateDate).Min() ?? DateTime.MaxValue;
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is **NOT** to project `DateTime?` to `DateTime` before calling `Min`.

Here's a `Nullable<int>` sample that does **not** project to `int` to illustrate how the `Min` and `Max` extensions behave with empty and different lists of nullable int's.

```
var foo = Enumerable.Empty<int?>();
Console.WriteLine(foo.Min());

foo = new int? [] { null, -20, 10 };
Console.WriteLine(foo.Min());
Console.WriteLine(foo.Max());
```

The output of the above is:

```
null 
-20
10
```

Instead of filtering the `DateTime?` instances in the list of Foos to only those that have values, allow the `Min` extension to work with the `DateTime?` values instead of projecting to `DateTime`. When you have an empty list (as in the example above) you'll get a `null` value from `Min` instead of the `InvalidOperationException`.